# upcasting and wrapper classes

Tags: java, types

Why is it that the primitive data types can be upcasted while the same can't be done with their corresponding wrapper classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the syntax is the same, casting a primitive is something quite different than casting a reference.

Comment: Exactly.  I would add "It's not 'upcasting.'  It's widening."  Assuming that the ubiquitous interpretation of this question is accurate.

Answer (score 4):

Primitive data types correspond to a particular way data is stored in memory. For example, a `double` and an `int` are stored very differently in memory, and to upcast from a `double` to an `int` involves changing the strategy used to store that data (from a version that stores decimal information to a version that does not).

Upcasting the wrapper classes is a different sort of upcasting. In that case, you are changing the type that the wrapper class is being treated as. To continue the example, the `Integer` and `Double` wrapper classes are subclasses of `Number`, which both wrappers can be upcast to. However, `Double` is not a subclass of `Integer`. Rather, they are siblings (that is, both extend `Number`). Thus, you cannot upcast from `Double` to `Integer`.

Answer (score 3):

Because neither `Byte` nor `Integer` inherit from `Long`, and `Float` doesn't inherit from `Double`.

Answer (score 0):

Because Long doesn't extend from Integer for example.  They can all be cast to Number...